# Encoding problem of the outfile file created by a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script which takes a input csv file,removes the first and the last double quotes of each line of the file and stores in the output csv file,the script works fine when the encoding of the input file is in utf-8 or ansi,but when the input file is of UCS-2 le bom encoding the output file is shows empty,is there a way to make the batch script work for any encoding type.I want to get the encoding of the output file as same as the input encoding file,for eg if the input file is in UCS-2 le bom encoding the output file should be also in UCS-2 le bom encoding and not something else

**NOTE:-Changing the encoding type of the input file is not an option in this case and want to do this without using powershell**

```
echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
::Set path name of the csv as argument
set "file_path=%1"
::Create a backup file of the main file by appending _backup.csv
COPY %file_path% %file_path:.csv=_backup.csv%
(
for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%G in (%file_path%) do (
    
    echo %%~G
    
))>new.csv
::contents of the new.csv will replace the contents of the main file,
move new.csv %file_path%
::del %tmp_path%
```

Comment: why not using powershell? It's available everywhere

Comment: Does `chcp` help to check and set the codepage?

Comment: @TenG i tried using chcp1252 but it does not change the encoding of the output file to the desired type

Answer (score 0):

Will this simpler replacement [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) work for you?

```sh
@Copy "%~1" "%~n1_backup%~x1" 1>NUL && (
    Rem Remove any line enclosing double-quotes from the input file contents
    (   For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type "%~n1_backup%~x1"') Do @Echo %%~G
    ) 1>"%~1")
```

*The `type` command should hopefully read your file without the encoding problem*

Comment: The content in the file is as expected,but it changes the encoding type to utf-8,i want to preserve the original encoding of the input file which is  UCS-2 le bom.is there any way?

Comment: I've just tested this on a UTF-16 LE BOM input file, which is essentially UCS-2 LE BOM, and a UTF-8 BOM and both worked exactly as expected outputting a file in the standard DOS ANSI codepage, 1252, (as reported by the same text editor which reported the input files as stated above). I cannot replicate your issue, the above code, with absolutely no changes, or additions works exactly as expected as a standalone batch file with the source CSV file passed to it as the first argument. The only reasonable reason I could envisage for a failure would be that your CSV file is open in another program.